# Set up docker remote execution on windows

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-for-windows

I have a windows workstation and a surface. I did setup my docker on my windows workstation. Is it possible to setup docker on my workstation such that I can do "rocker run" on my surface and the docker actually runs on my workstation and sends the output back to my surface.

I searched online for it; I found a lot of demos for doing that on Linux but very few on windows.